# CURL impossible to connect

Tags: php, curl

I posted through internet some ads and I just learned the cURL techniques to check all my account (like mailbox).

Problem is: in some website, the script works: the cookies is created and the text are taken.

BUT this is not connected! When you open the cookie, it's marked 'false' and the text taken is the offline version. So i want to know, what can I do to archive to connect me of this kind of website?

My code:

```
 <?php
 //connexion via page de login
 $username="xxxx";
 $password="passxxxx";
 $url="http://www.garder-mes-enfants.fr/";
 $cookie="cookie.txt";

 $postdata = "username=".$username."&passwd=".$password;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "index.php?option=com_user&amp;Itemid=305&amp;lang=fr");
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url . "index.php");
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 $result = curl_exec ($ch);
 //fin de connexion, on ne ferme pas la curl en cour pour l'utiliser après

 //récupération du code source de la page dans un fichier texte pour traiter les informations via php
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."nounou/SURESNES/115043-assistante-maternelle-agreee-cherche-3-petits-bouts-de-chou.html");
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url . "S-identifier.html");
 $ret = curl_exec($ch);
 if ($ret === FALSE) {
     die(curl_error());
 }
 $nom_local="test.txt";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
         if ($nom_local) {
             $fp = fopen($nom_local, 'w') or die("Le fichier '$nom_local' n'a pu être ouvert en écriture");
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
         } else {
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
         }
         $ret = curl_exec($ch);
         if ($nom_local) {
             fclose($fp);
         }
         curl_close($ch);
         if ($ret === FALSE) {
             die("Une erreur a été rencontrée : " . curl_error());
         }
 echo $ret;
```

Comment: `com_user&amp;Itemid` you probably want to change that to `com_user&Itemid`

Comment: thanks arnaud, just tried but still the same! snif

Comment: Did you change all `&amp;` to `&` ?